# What is the difference between document.write and document.innerHTML and other javascript issue please

Tags: javascript, document.write

I am having an issue trying to put a  tag inside a document.write() call. I think this is happening because the document.write() already lives within another  tag.

I saw somewhere online there is also a document.innerHTML() call. Does anyone know if this will help me or if not, is there another way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: innerHTML is not a function, but a property you'd need to assign to. But: have you searched before asking?

Comment: You want to add a tag? Have you tried using the dom to insert a new node (tag)? Maybe you should start here: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics

Comment: neither `document.write` nor `document.innerHTML` are the proper way to construct HTML dynamically. you should should DOM methods such as `createElement` and `appendChild`

Comment: @jbabey: Using `innerHTML` is fine. It's fairly consistent cross-browser (there **are** gotchas), now included in a specification, and dramatically faster for many use cases than the equivalent DOM calls would be.

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` can be used to emit markup during the parsing of the page. It cannot be used for modifying the page after it's parsed. The output of `document.write` goes straight into the parser as though it had been in the HTML document in the first place. So for instance:

```
<body>
<script>
document.write("<p>");
</script>
hi there</p>
```

looks **exactly** the same to the browser as

```
<body>
<p>hi there</p>
```

`innerHTML`, which is not a function but rather a *property*, exists on all DOM element instances, and can be used to set their content, using markup. This, along with the various DOM methods available on instances, is the primary way that dynamic web pages are done. For example:

```
<body>
<p id="target">Hi there</p>
<script>
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "Updated by <strong>code</strong>";
</script>
</body>
```

...changes the paragraph from saying "hi there" to saying "Updated by **code**".

More to explore:

- [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml)
- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [DOM2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)
- [DOM3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)
- [HTML5 Web Application APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

Comment: Only 7 specification links? Slacker. :D

Comment: What if several document.write in same <script> ?

Comment: So in compiling same input there are no difference in generated code? I think writeCapture replace DOM blocking document.write by innerHTML ...
https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture/tree/writeCapture2

Comment: Steve Sounder who made ControlJS say: My solution is to override document.write and capture the output for each script one at a time. If there's no document.write output then proceed to the next script. If there is output then I create an element (for now a SPAN), insert it into the DOM immediately before the SCRIPT tag that's being executed, and set the SPAN's innerHTML to the output from document.write. This works pretty well.

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho - If there are several, they all output (in order) to the token stream being parsed by the HTML parser. Re replacing `document.write` as described: That would break some number of sites who do, for instance, things like the first example above.